# How to apply "text-overflow: ellipsis" property on parent div which is already having more than one child elements

Tags: html, css

I need to apply `text-overflow: ellipsis` property on a div which is having 3 child divs.

```html
<div class='external-div'>
  <div> Div 1 </div>
  <div> Div 2 </div>
  <div> Div 3 </div>
</div>
```

So in the above code, I can not apply `text-overflow` on child divs because all of the child divs are having the dynamic data. So complete string should get ellipse according to functionality. So what CSS should I write for this?

Comment: Can you show us an example with a problem, including content in the div elements and CSS? If we can see your attempt, we can figure out what needs to change.

Comment: Hi @JonUleis Thanks for your reply. Actually, i am using this in a very large project. So it's bit difficult to explain by posting the code. But i'll try to make one codepen example so that it'll be easy to understand the problem.

Comment: @JonUleis here is the codepen example
https://codepen.io/jainshravandeveloper/pen/zdRqRp?page=1&

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `overflow, whitespace, width, and display` properties in order for it to work.

To select the divs you want, you need to select the parent div's children which you can do by `.external-div div{ \CSS\ }`

If you have children within the div, you just have to select them as well (ex. `.external-div div, .external-div div p{ \CSS\ }` keep adding commas for each element.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7phmnsx9/)

Comment: Hi @mickey-b Thanks for your reply. I tried this solution but it'll apply the overflow property on each and every child div which i don't want. I just want that if the overflow happens in complete string.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, not sure if you'll get this in time, but if that is the case then I'm not sure that can be done, however you could try it by setting the children's properties to the `initial` settings using the child selector (i.e. `.parentDiv > .childObject{ CSS CODE }` Hope I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
.external-div {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try this :

```css
#div1 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
}
#div1 span.dots{
    width:15%;
    float:right;
    padding-left:5%;
}
.before-dots{
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='external-div' id="div1">
  <div class="before-dots">
    <span> Div 1 </span>
    <span> Div 2 </span>
    <span> Div 3 </span>
    <span> Div 4 </span>
    <span> Div 5 </span>
    <span> Div 7 </span>
    <span> Div 8 </span>
    <span> Div 9 </span>
    <span> Div 10 </span>
  </div>

  <span class="dots">....</span>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This is the 08' way, to anyone read this in in 2022 - you can do better!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my parent div `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work with `div` child elements

The html format was like

```html
<div
  style="height: inherit; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; display: block; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 260px; min-width: 260px;"
>
  <div style="display: inline;">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>
  <div style="display: inline;">zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba</div>
  <div style="display: inline;">1234567890987654321</div>
</div>
```